# C# .net Core Connection string is not well-formed

Tags: c#, oracle, .net-core, oracle12c

I've changed my driver for connection to Oracle and got error

> Connection string is not well-formed

I had unofficial Oracle driver `dotNetCore.Data.OracleClient Version=1.0.0`

Now I use `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core Version=2.18.3`

My connection string looks like there

```
Data Source = ORACLE.HOSTS:1521/pdb_prod;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=xxxx; Password=xxxx;Pooling=false;
```

And it works well before

Whats wrong with my connection string?

Comment: @mason That string worked well with previous driver

Comment: Connection strings.com : https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/

Comment: @Badda_Bing my connection string looks same like in this site

Comment: Does using capitals matter? PERSIST SECURITY INFO; USER ID...?

Comment: @Badda_Bing I didn't try it, do you think it may help to me?

Comment: I guess there is no harm in trying Igor.  I also like you do not think that you are missing any arguments, but I am not sure if the argument names in these strings are case-sensitive or not. I usually just copy/paste the ones I need and fill in the details.

Comment: @Badda_Bing It's not helped to me. Because same code and same connection string work well on local machine but on host doesn't. Now I don't know why

Comment: Maybe you have an issue with quoting or special characters. Try `OracleConnectionStringBuilder ` to build the connectionString

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit But if I had quotes or special characters, then this code wouldn't work on the local machine.

Comment: Does the `sqlnet.ora` file contains `ezconnect ` in the `NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH` attribute (see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10835/sqlnet.htm#NETRF192)?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit problem was detected - connection string is reading from ENV and there it was newline character in the end of the connection string. =) My admins are the best, but even they sometimes make mistakes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem detected - the connection string is read from ENV, and at the end of the connection string there was a newline character.

My admins are the best, but even they sometimes make mistakes

Answer (score 1):

Don't put space between equalities `Data Source = ...`

```
Data Source=ORACLE.HOSTS:1521/pdb_prod;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=xxxx; Password=xxxx;Pooling=false;
```

you can also try

```
Data Source=//host:[port]/[service_name]
```

Btw, I dont have experience with `Pooling=true` you may try without it and if it succeeds you can add it

Comment: Problem was detected - connection string is reading from ENV and there it was newline character in the end of the connection string. =) My admins are the best, but even they sometimes make mistakes